# Find primary key for entity object

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is it possible for JPA to retrieve the primary key or entity for an entity object from database?

Sample Entity:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    private long key;

    private String someProperty;
    private int anotherProperty;

    // ...
}
```

Finder:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(arguments);
em.persist(entity); // entity has a key now

// have another entity object with the same arguments, thus having the same properties
SomeEntity sameEntity = new SomeEntity(arguments);
Entity persistedEntity = em.???(sameEntity);
```

Is it possible to find the persisted entity without building a query from all it's properties?

Edit: Because of the comments, some more information abount my goal:
My service receives XML objects that are unmarshalled and then persisted. The clients don't know which objects have been saved and transmit everything. According to this, the service must filter objects, which are already saved.

Comment: em.find(SomeEntity.class, pkValue) ? as per every JPA tutorial

Comment: I don't know the primary key when trying to save the created object. That's the crucial point. When a new object is about to be saved, i'd like to prevent persisting the same entity values multiple times.

Comment: When you persist an object, you do get the persisted object, isnt't it ?

Comment: According to your last comment, you might want to use `@Unique` columns.

Comment: Your `@ID` seems to be a technical key, maybe a generated one. Is it possible for you to switch to some business key, maybe with some data you know looking at one of your new Objects?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot alter the entity.

Comment: If you can't change your entity to tell JPA what makes your entity unique, then you will have to do it yourself.  Create a query passing in the data you wish to use to determine if an entity exists for it or not, execute the query, and then merge or persist based on the result.  em.createNamedQuery("yourQueryName", Entity.class).setParameter("param1",sameEntity.getVal1()).setParameter("param2",sameEntity.getVal2())

Comment: What you are searching for is called [QBE (query by example)](/questions/2880209/jpa-findbyexample)

Comment: @TobiasLiefke That is exactly what i was looking for!